# How To Stop Auto Reload data in Firebase Web Application?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i change firebase database them my web application automatically reload data without refresh my web page.
I just want to Stop this functionality.

Comment: Please add your code, downvoter you can comment your suggestion..!

Comment: " Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 8):

I assume you're using `javascript` because you have web application , so what you can do is call `once` method not `on` on the reference

here the callback will executed whenever your data changed

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts');
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

but here the callback will be executed only one time

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts');
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```